# How do I configure a custom converter that returns json, instead of a string, in NewtonSoft.Json?

Tags: json.net, nettopologysuite

I have a simple model that contains a NetTopologySuite Polygon:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(MyPolygonConverter))]
    public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon poly { get; set; }
}
```

And I've build a custom converter, using NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJson:

```
public class MyPolygonConverter : JsonConverter<Polygon>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Polygon value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var geoJsonSerializer = NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJsonSerializer.Create();

        using var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        using var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);

        geoJsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value);
        var geoJson = stringWriter.ToString();
        writer.WriteValue(geoJson);
    }
    ...
}
```

And then I create a model object and serialize it:

```
var model = new MyModel
{
    poly = new Polygon(new LinearRing(new[]
    {
        new Coordinate(-100, 45),
        new Coordinate(-98, 45),
        new Coordinate(-99, 46),
        new Coordinate(-100, 45),
    }))
};

var geoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.None, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
```

And what I get contains the Polygon as an escaped GeoJson string:

```
{
    "poly" : "{\"type\":\"Polygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[-100.0,45.0],[-98.0,45.0],[-99.0,46.0],[-100.0,45.0]]]}"
}
```

What I want is the Polygon as json, in the json object:

```
{
    "poly" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
            [
                [-100.0,45.0],
                [-98.0,45.0],
                [-99.0,46.0],
                [-100.0,45.0]
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

What I'm thinking is that I shouldn't be using a JsonConverter at all, but something else.

But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JsonWriter.WriteRawValue(string)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRawValue.htm) to write a raw JSON value directly to the JSON output:

```
writer.WriteRawValue(geoJson);
```

That being said, [`GeoJsonSerializer`](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/blob/develop/src/NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJSON/GeoJsonSerializer.cs) is a subclass of Newtonsoft's own [`JsonSerializer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) so you can just pass the incoming [`JsonWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) in to its [`Serialize()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize.htm) method:

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Polygon value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var geoJsonSerializer = NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJsonSerializer.Create();
    geoJsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HM6YBt).

The only difference between `GeoJsonSerializer` and the base class is that `NullValueHandling.Ignore` is enabled by default and several converters are added, so you could also just use this serializer to serialize *your entire model*, thereby eliminating the need to add `[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(MyPolygonConverter))]` to your model:

```
var serializer = NetTopologySuite.IO.GeoJsonSerializer.CreateDefault(
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented, // Or none, if you prefer
    });
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb))
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, model);

var geoJson = sb.ToString();
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nRHHwS).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.